# Silverlight 3 DataGrid - Rounded Corners

Tags: silverlight, .net-3.5, silverlight-3.0, datagrid

Is there an easy way to give rounded corners to the boundary of a DataGrid in Silverlight 3?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066475/silverlight-scrollviewer-with-rounded-corners) for giving rounded corners to any FrameworkElement by attaching a Blend clipping behavior with a specified CornerRadius.

You could write your own logic for the clipping behavior or use the one from the [Expression Blend Samples CodePlex](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/28511?projectName=expressionblend#494852) page. It would then be as simple referencing System.Windows.Interactivity.dll from the Blend SDK and dropping the behavior on the element in Blend or writing out the XAML:

```
<data:DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <samples:ClippingBehavior CornerRadius="15"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</data:DataGrid>
```

Its a nice reusable way to give rounded corners to any element without relying on a border or an element with corner radii properties.

Comment: I'll definitely try this. However, I did use Tim Heuer's solution which was similar to this (but did not use Behaviors), and there was a problem with that. When i launched my solution, the corners would not be rounded. Then I would restore the window size, and then Maximize it, and the corners would then show up as rounded. I hope the same does not happen with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Border.Background>
  <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
     <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
     <GradientStop Color="#FF508EB1" Offset="1"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
</Border.Background>

<Grid Background="{x:Null}"  x:Name="MainGrid" >
<Grid.Effect>
  <DropShadowEffect />
</Grid.Effect>

    <...>
</Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb qn, but is the above modifying the default template for a DataGrid?

Comment: I tried this one. It simply gave it a gradient border, and yet no rounded corners. FAIL

Answer (score -1):

```
<Border CornerRadius="5">
    <toolkit:DataGrid />
</Border>
```